# join in r markdown sql chunk returns: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'col' is ambiguous, could be: a.col, b.col

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, r-markdown, knitr

I have two tables I'd like to join in an sql chunk using r markdown. There are so many columns, I do not want to specify all of them in the select statement. In HUE Impala/Hive or in a spark shell I can just `select *`, but in an sql chunk `select *` throws an error.
Here is a minimal working example:

````
```{sql connection=sc, eval=TRUE}
with tmp1 as (
   select 'mark' as name, 1 as mark
   union
   select 'tim' as name, 2 as mark
),
tmp2 as (
   select 'mark' as name, 'a' as class
   union
   select 'tim' as name, 'b' as class
)
select
  *
from
  tmp1
inner join
  tmp2
  on tmp1.name = tmp2.name
    ```
````

I get the error

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'name' is ambiguous, could be: a.name, b.name.;
```

Why does this not work?